# Deep Learning with Python IMDB dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am currently working through Chollet's "Deep Learning with Python." My neural network is running just fine but I am having an issue with plotting the training and validation loss> Here is the code:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(
num_words=10000)

max([max(sequence) for sequence in train_data])

word_index = imdb.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict(
[(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_review = ' '.join(
[reverse_word_index.get(i - 3, '?') for i in train_data[0]])

import numpy as np

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]

y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

history_dict = history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Toward the end, I am getting a "name 'acc' is not defined" error. Not sure why this is the case as I am following exactly what Chollet has in the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)` doesn't seem to stand for anything. I guess this is written by mistake.

To get the desired output for the plot, you need to create a list that contains values for the x-axis, which is determined by the number of epochs.
So this should be the full code:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(
num_words=10000)

max([max(sequence) for sequence in train_data])

word_index = imdb.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict(
[(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])
decoded_review = ' '.join(
[reverse_word_index.get(i - 3, '?') for i in train_data[0]])

import numpy as np

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]

y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

epochs = 20
history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

history_dict = history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

x_axis = [i for i in range(1,epochs+1)]

plt.plot(x_axis, loss_values, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(x_axis, val_loss_values, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```